# Javascript promises fetching json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, query-string

I am trying to learn promises in javascript and I came across [this short video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obaSQBBWZLk),  there is a complete code from it on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ArvFxI0gWmajTpDaOSB?p=preview).
What I wonder about in this code is in this line in promises.js file:

```
return $.get('tweets.json?id=' + profile.id);
```

First of all, why do we even need to pass any parameters there, since there is no profile.id field in tweets.json file, and when removing it I get the same results. If there was that field in tweets.json how would we achieve to get only tweets from the users that we pass with get request?
I have tried something like this but it doesn't work:

In promises.json I have changed the get request to:

```
 return $.get('tweets.json?profile=' + profile.id);
```

And have added a new field to the tweets.json file, but only to the first tweet:

```
 {
 "id": 1,
 "profile": 12302151,
 "tweet": "OMG, worst day ever, my BF @BobbyBoo dumped me",
 "usersMentioned": [
 {
  "id": 10,
  "username": "BobbyBoo"
 }
 ]
},
```

I was then expecting that I will only get that one tweet for that user, but I am still getting the whole list

Comment: tweets.json is just a static file. It doesn't matter what's in the query string (the part after the `?`); it will just be ignored. If you were calling an actual web service, the query string could have meaning, and I think that's what they're trying to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!